# What numbers can be approximated by ratios of numbers containing only specified digits?

Tags: rational-numbers

Let $D$ be a subset of the decimal digits $ \{ 0, 1, 2, \ldots, 9\}$, with $D \neq \{0\}$ or $\emptyset$.  Let $N$ be the set of positive integers whose decimal representations (without leading $0$'s) consist only of digits in $D$.  Let $R$ be the set of ratios of numbers in $N$:  $R = \{ {x \over y}: x, y \in N\}$.  What are the density properties of $R$ in the positive reals?

Clearly, if $D$ contains only one digit, the only accumulation points of $R$ are the powers of $10$ (as well as $0$ and $\infty$, if you consider the compactification of the positive reals), and if $D = \{0,\ldots,9\}$, $R$ is the positive rationals and is dense in the positive reals.  Numerical evidence suggests that if $D = \{1,2,3,4\}$, $R$ is dense in the positive reals.

For what sets $D$ is $R$ dense in the positive reals?  Generalize for all integral bases $\ge 2$.

Comment: What is your personal work  ?

Comment: $1/11,10/111,100/1101,1000/11001,\dots$ would seem to converge to $1/11$, in contradiction to your claim about $D=\{\,0,1\,\}$.

Comment: And $100/101, 10000/10101, 100000/1010101,\ldots$ converges to $0.99.$

Comment: Indeed, the closure of $R$ for $\{0,1\}$ is uncountable, even if you restrict to denominators that are powers of $10$.

Comment: Care to engage with the comments, Dale?

Comment: Other people have edited my question.  One change was to note that $0$ is an accumulation point of any $R$, which I had overlooked because I was only looking for positive accumulation points.  Another change was to replace $D=\{1\}$ with $D=\{0,1\}$ on an assertion that the former does not cause $R$ to have accumulation points at the powers of $10$.  But unless I am mistaken, an integer of $n+m$ $1$'s divided by an integer of $m$ $1$'s approaches $10^n$ as $m$ goes to infinity.

Comment: Maybe you should roll back the offending edit, Dale.

Comment: I've updated the question to correct the bit about when $R$ has accumulation points at the powers of 10.  I've also expanded the description a bit to clarify attention toward the positive reals and that $0$ and $\infty$ are elements of the compatification thereof.